# Both of alarms triggers as soon as I start Alarm service

Tags: android

As soon as I start `AlarmService`, both alarms trigger without caring about the time saved in SQLite database with format `HH:MM`. 
I tried the following code:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        long oneDay = 24*3600*1000; //24 hours


        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), StartTimeIntentReceiver.class);


        final PendingIntent sender1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 192837, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), EndTimeIntentReceiver.class);

        final PendingIntent sender2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 192837, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("EventsDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from TIntervals", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        String starttime = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("stime"));
        String endtime = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("etime"));
        c.moveToNext();
        c.close();

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        try {
            long sTime = simpleDateFormat.parse(starttime).getTime();
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sTime, oneDay, sender1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        simpleDateFormat1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        try {
            long eTime = simpleDateFormat.parse(endtime).getTime();
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, eTime, oneDay, sender2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

}

I also tried the following code which starts the service but never fires an alarm:




public class AlarmService extends Service {
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        long oneDay = 24*3600*1000; //24 hours

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), StartTimeIntentReceiver.class);



        final PendingIntent sender1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 192837, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), EndTimeIntentReceiver.class);

        final PendingIntent sender2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 192837, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("EventsDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from TIntervals", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        String starttime = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("stime"));
        String endtime = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("etime"));
        c.moveToNext();
        c.close();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int hours = Integer.valueOf(starttime.split(":")[0]);
        int minutes = Integer.valueOf(starttime.split(":")[1]);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), oneDay, sender1);

        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int hours2 = Integer.valueOf(endtime.split(":")[0]);
        int minutes2 = Integer.valueOf(endtime.split(":")[1]);
        calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours2);
        calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes2);
        calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), oneDay, sender2);



        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

Please help and recommend any alterations in any of the above code. Thanks.

Comment: because you use the same ID for both of alarms (192837). this will override first alarm.use separate ID for your alarms

Comment: I tried 192838 for sender2 but same issue for first code. Plz try to understand my question. I mean if I stored "05:02" as startTime and "05:05" as endTime and start the service at any time like "03:00" or "07:05". still both the alarms triggers at that time when I used to start alarmservice. No matter what is time. plz help.

Comment: I think I failed to convert String HH:MM to time which i got from sqlite database. Plz someone help to get time from it or convert convert it to time so that it can be used for alarm service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set my alarms in this way.it's work for me

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            myIntent, 0);
    Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8); // At the hour you wanna fire
    firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // Particular minute
    firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);// particular second
    firingCal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);//in my case I specified AM-PM

    long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
    long currentTime = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();

    if (intendedTime >= currentTime) // you can add buffer time too here to
                                        // ignore some small differences in
                                        // milliseconds
    {
        // set from today
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime, pendingIntent);

    } else {
        firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    }
```

this function set alarm for every day at 8 AM.

Comment: Sorry but It is not working. I think I failed to convert String HH:MM to time which i got from sqlite database. Plz someone help to get time from it or convert convert it to time so that it can be used for alarm service.

Comment: so post your string that you get from sqlite here until see what is it's style

Comment: Thanks sir it helped me a lot. It worked for me after some alterations. thanks again.